# Web application hangs after multiple requests

Tags: apache, tomcat

The application is using Apache Server as a web server and Tomcat as an application server.

Operations/requests can be triggered from the UI, which can take time to return from the server as it does some processing like fetching data from the database and performing calculations on that data. This time depends on the amount of data in the database and the duration of data it is processing. It could be as long as 30min to an hour or 2 min's based on the parameters.

Apart from this, there are some other calls which fetche small amount of data from the database and return immediately.

Now when I have multiple, say 4 or 5 of these long heavy calls to the server, and they are currently running, when I make a call that is supposed to be smaller and return immediately, this call also hangs as it never reaches my controller.

I am unable to find a way to debug this issue or find a resolution. Please let me know if in case you happen to know how to proceed with this issue.

I am using Spring, with c3p0 connection pooling with Hibernate.

Comment: 30 min to return a response seems too long, what will you do if someone clicks on these "heavy calls" and then closes the browser?? Anyways, as you said that the call never reaches the controller, there might be connection requests limit on the web server that is causing this. Try mod_status on apache web server to check.

Comment: Hey! Ankit, These calls are part of a view, and a web page can have multiple views. Think of the views as a key in your keyboard, which are independent fo the other keys. Whenever the page id loaded each view sends a ajax call to the server to restore it's value. Hence even if the browser is closed the values calculated are restored back. And thanks for the hint I will try to explore `mod_status`.

Comment: as I wrote I remembered that I face the same issue in my development environment also. And in my development environment I don't use Apache. I guess this might not be the reason, what do you think?

Comment: Do you have low value for maxConnections/acceptCount .. in tomcat server.xml? Monitor your tomcat thread status and see if it is limiting the number of requests on your server. Check here for available parameters - https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: I checked for these variables but they are not configured, at least on my eclipse server. And there defaults values are much larger.

Comment: Hey @Ankit I found out what was the issue. I am tagging you in case you are interested in the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out what was wrong with the application, and thought about sharing it in case someone somewhere faces the same issue. It turns out nothing was wrong with the application server or the web server, when technically speaking it was the browsers fault.

I found out that the browser can only have a limited number of open concurrent calls to a domain. In the case of the latest version of chrome at the time of writing is 6. This is something all the browsers do to prevent DDOS attacks.

As in my application, the HTTP calls take a lot of time to return until the calculations are completed several HTTP calls accumulate concurrently and as a result, the browser stops sending any further calls after the 6th concurrent call and it feels like the application is unresponsive. You can read about the maximum no of concurrent calls by a browser in SO.

A possible solution I have thought is either polling or even better Long Polling. I would have used WebSockets but then we would need to make a lot of changes.